# Почему записываются в файлик part2_sorted.txt знаки вопроса?

Tags: java, файлы, сортировка

Мой код рабочий и в файл part2.txt записывает всё правильно. Но при сортировке и считывании данных с файла part2.txt в массив начинаются проблемы. Когда я хочу отсортированный массив записать уже в конечный файл part2_sorted.txt - оно записывает везде знаки вопроса. Как этому помешать и сделать корректную запись отсортированного массива?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Part2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\kostevich.bogdan\\IdeaProjects\\untitled13\\part2.txt");

        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int[] input = new int[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            input[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 50);
        }

        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                fileWriter.write(input[i] + " ");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int[] output = new int[input.length];

        try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
             Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileReader)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
                output[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            algorithm(output);
        }

        File file2 = new File("C:\\Users\\kostevich.bogdan\\IdeaProjects\\untitled13\\part2_sorted.txt");

        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file2)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
                fileWriter.write(output[i]);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        StringBuilder stringBuilderInput = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder stringBuilderOutput = new StringBuilder();

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
             Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(new FileReader(file2))) {
            stringBuilderInput.append("input ==> ");
            stringBuilderOutput.append("output ==> ");

            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                stringBuilderInput.append(input[i] + " ");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
                stringBuilderOutput.append(output[i] + " ");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println(stringBuilderInput.toString());
            System.out.println(stringBuilderOutput.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void algorithm(int[] arr) {

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (arr[i] < arr[j]) {
                    int temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Miron но сортировка у меня происходит и всё верно выводит, только вот в конечный файл не правильно записывает...

Comment: мой косяк, пойду изучать мат. часть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в следующем - в первом случае вы вызываете `void write(String str) throws IOException` класса `Writer`, а во втором - `void write(int c) throws IOException` класса `OutputStreamWriter`, который "Writes a single character"(то есть, один `char` кодируется одним `integer`'ом.).
Возникающую ошибку предлагаю решить следующим способом - сначала запишите все в одну строчку с помощью `StringBuilder`, а потом запишите в файл его(получившегося экземляра класса `StringBuilder`) строковое представление.